# Add a rule above and below each figure (including caption)

Tags: floats, rules

I have a document with a lot of figures and I want to modify them so that there is a horizontal rule above and below each figure so it stands out from the text. That is, I want it to look something like this:

> text .... text .... text ....
>
> text .... text .... text ....
>
> -------------------------------- % rule
>
> FIGURE HERE
>
> ...........
>
> caption of figure: blah blah
>
> ------------------------------- % another rule
>
> text .... text .... text ....

I know I can individually go and modify each figure individually, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this automatically to all figures....

Comment: See the `caption` package documentation, § 4, Own Enhancements, the command `DeclareCaptionFormat`.

Comment: I will look into this, but my understanding is that the `caption` package allows me to add rules above and below the caption, but not above the figure.

Comment: Oh! It seems I misunderstood. Do you want a rule *above* the figure, and another *below* the caption?

Comment: That is exactly right. I want a rule above the figure, and one below the caption, so that the entire thing is separated visual from the regular text.

Comment: I think `tcolorbox` might help. And the rules should have the width of the figure, more or less?

Comment: Rules should be \textwidth, regardless of the width of the figure.

Comment: In this case you can use `tcolorbox`or `mdframed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `float`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@tbruled{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\normalfont}%
  \let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse
}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{tbruled}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

Some text before your figure. Some text before your figure. Some text before your figure. 
Some text before your figure.
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{My caption}

\end{figure}
Some text after your figure. Some text after your figure. Some text after your figure. 
Some text after your figure.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's see what the commands do:

```
\def\@fs@cfont{\normalfont}%              The font for the caption label
\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain %              Use plain style caption
\def\@fs@pre{\hrule\kern2pt}%             The rule at the top
\def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%      The rule at the bottom
\def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}% Material to be inserted before the caption
\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse %              We don't want the caption is moved at the top
```

Should you want more space after the top rule, change into

```
\def\@fs@pre{\hrule\kern12pt}%
```

or whatever space you deem good. Similarly for the rule at the bottom.

Comment: Excellent. You don't have to do this, but I would love to learn what each of those commands do in the definition of tbruled.  

Also, how can I adjust the vertical space below and above the rules ?

Comment: @johnymm Your wish is my command

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just create your own environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newenvironment{myfigure}%
    {\begin{figure}[htb]\hrule\vspace{3ex}\centering}%
    {\vspace{3ex}\hrule\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
Some text before your figure. Some text before your figure. Some text before your figure. Some text before your figure.%
\begin{myfigure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{My caption}
\end{myfigure}
Some text after your figure. Some text after your figure. Some text after your figure. Some text after your figure.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it would involve me going into the multiple tex.files that I have and change every instance of `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`, which I was hoping to avoid.